# Android: Set next and previous view dynamically in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, user-interface, viewflipper

I'm currently trying to use a viewflipper for switching through a list of entities. The start point is the detail view of an entity.

The scenario is easy: When the user swipes left the previous entity should inflate the view to which is slided, if the user swipes right the next entity should inflate the view to which is slided.

I tried to use the methods viewFlipper.getNextFocusLeftId() and viewFlipper.getNextFocusRightId() to get the ID of the next view. But that just returns -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html
this will help i think. compatibility library is needed for that http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html